# Issue with box-sizing border-box and min-width in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, border-box

I'm using the **box-sizing:border-box** model. When an **inline-block** element with a **min-width** is contained in an **inline-block** element (container), the container is too wide in Internet Explorer 9. Works as expected in FF 10.0, Chrome 17.0, Opera 11.5 and Safari 5.1.2.

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hakan/5Ng7k/)

By the way, **width** instead of **min-width** works like a charm.

Any ideas?

Comment: max-width has the same problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi came across your post when Googling for a similar issue with IE 8,  although IE 8 supports box-sizing and min-height/width, from my tests, it seems IE 8 ignores border-box when using min-height/width on the same element

E.g.

```
#box {
   min-height: 20px;
   padding:4px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**IE 8 height** = 28px, **Chrome 20 height** = 20px;

Solution using css browser selectors http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

```
#box {
       min-height: 20px;
       padding:4px;
       box-sizing:border-box;
  }

 .ie8 #box, .ie9 #box {
       min-height: 12px;
       padding:4px;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation, I've seen it happening on a website I am developing and suspected this was the case but just wanted to confirm since officially min-height/min-width is supported. I <3 IE8 :)

Comment: Thanks @htmlr. I'm not at all happy having to set the min-height/width in two different ways, nor being forced to use "css browser selectors". Still, since this seems to be a bug in IE 8/9 your solution makes some sense.

Answer (score 2):

### My Issue

I see the border-box value being applied in *IE8* developer tools inspector. Therefore, I know border-box is working, especially as expected when width(or height) is set. But since I am using min-height for my height (and OP is using min-width), my min value is not working. The issue is therefore:

**IE's min-height/min-width does not factor in border-box**

```
.box {
     padding: 30px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     min-height: 200px;
}    

<div class="box">Awesome Box</div>
```

- IE8: 260px (30px from padding top and 30px from padding bottom). Does not work.
- FireFox: 200px height. (min's factor in border-box). Works.

### My solution:

Don't put the padding on the same element as you put the min-values AND the border-box - (you may not need border-box sizing anymore if you separate these).

```
.box {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     min-height: 200px;
}
.box-inner {
     padding: 30px;
}  

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">Awesome Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is nice and may well be used as the accepted answer. The reason I preferred @htmlr's answer is that when I eventually drop support for IE 8/9 I don't have to change the HTML, but just cut out the .ie8/.ie9 rules in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this, but came across the question while googling for a fix myself. Fortunately, in my case, I'm able to get by for now with setting the width instead of min-width, although that might be a problem in the future.

Anyway, I just wanted to add that the same problem exists if the min-width element and its container are both floated instead of inline-block, as well.

Here's an update to the original fiddle showing it with `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ng7k/24/