# IE8 layout with min-height and border-box

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, border-box

First let me say that it seems Internet Explorer 8 completely ignores *box-sizing: border-box;* declaration on a box, when there is a *min-height* set on it as well (this post confirms that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714178/3355252).

Now let me describe what I need to accomplish. Here's my site (much simplified): http://jsfiddle.net/ttKP3/. Doctype is HTML 4.01 Strict.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="main">main</div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header,
#footer {
  height: 100px;
}

#main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

What I need is *footer* at the very bottom of the screen and the *main* box filling the whole screen from the top to the bottom. Also, when the content gets bigger (click *Add content* in JSFiddle few times) I need the *main* box to enlarge and *footer* to move accordingly.

It renders just fine in Chrome and Firefox. You probably won't be able to run it in IE8 (it doesn't render JSFiddle), but *border-box* property on *main* is completely ignored and so that *main* box is 200px higher than it should be - the *footer* is below the visible area of screen.

As it looks like it couldn't be handled by using *border-box* and *min-height*, I'm looking for any other solution for IE8. The only one that came to my mind was using *calc*, that is *height: calc(100% - 200px);* but IE8 doesn't support that as well. By the way I have a conditional adding *ie8* class on *html* element when ran in IE8, so I don't need a cross browser solution - just CSS to get the desired layout in that particular browser.

Comment: hi Robert, google "css sticky footer" (or even do a search for it on SO).  There are tons of sites showing you how to do what you want (without the use of box-sizing) - [this is one that I did using box-sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9DLeg/) but not sure how it works in ie8, it could be ok as I didn't use min-height

Comment: Check this demo http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: Yes, it looks like there are many threads for *sticky footer* on the web. Wish I'd look for that before! The one Vel posted has a bit different HTML structure - there is a wrapper containing header, footer and main - but I bet I'll find a solution that can be aplied to the HTML structure I have. So thank you both Vel and Pete.

Comment: @Robert the one in my edited comment above uses your html structure - you just need a couple of extra divs inside your main and a wrapper - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9DLeg/

Comment: @Pete It looks like it should work as now *border-box* and *min-height* are used on different divs, but I need some time to test it out. I'll add a comment when I work it out.

Comment: @Pete It looks like your method works very well (IE8 included), but after some tinkering I've found a solution that is cleaner - doesn't require any markup changes. I'm going to post it soon. Anyway thanks once more for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading once more [this sticky footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) post on CSS-tricks and tinkering a bit, I found a clean solution that doesn't require any markup changes (you can do with only 3 containers: *header*, *main* and a *footer*) nor using *box-sizing* at all. It works in IE8 just as well.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header,
#footer {
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

#footer {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

#main {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Space for header and footer. */
#main:before,
#main:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
}
```

You may like to apply the margins to *main* instead of *header* and *footer*.

Here's my fiddle with this solution applied: http://jsfiddle.net/ttKP3/1/